# Why does the never type not work with control flow analysis?

Tags: typescript

I have the following construct (using strictNullChecks):

```
function neverReturns(): never {
    throw new Error();
}

const maybeString: string | null = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hi" : null;

if (!maybeString) {
    neverReturns();
    // throw new Error();
}

maybeString.substr(0, 1); // <- Object is possibly 'null'.
```

When directly throwing an Error in the condition, the compiler figures out that maybeString can't be null afterwards and accepts the code.

I would expect the same behaviour when calling a function with return type `never`. However the compiler complains that maybeString could be `null`.

Is there a reason for this or is this a missing feature in TypeScript?

Comment: It's a missing feature. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred workaround is to use a `return` statement at the point where you invoke the throwing function:

```
if (!maybeString) {
    return neverReturns();
}

maybeString.substr(0, 1); // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `else` branch. Since it may or may not evaluate `!maybeString` to `true`. In any case it may travel through the `never` return type and forget about it.

If you use it like this:

```
if (!maybeString) {
    neverReturns();
} else {
    maybeString.substr(0, 1); // not going to be null
}
```

Then your else branch knows that it can not be null anymore.